# href not being rendered using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive written below code to create url href using javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var js = [{"title":"New ECB Boss Christine Lagarde Made A Serious Bitcoin Warning","link":"https://www.forbes.com/sites/billybambrough/2019/07/07/new-ecb-boss-christine-lagarde-made-a-serious-bitcoin-warning/","text":"Bitcoin and other crypto-assets have long divided traditional economists and bankers with some warning over their instability and others ...","img":"https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-cf7C5AWRZ2mt1qip3sV9MzLok1tGn0CAInRO6kqP1J5b_VQQdQRmKXW8NsNi2BTxOYnSl-Q"},{"title":"Bitcoin Approaches $11500 as Top Cryptos See Gains","link":"https://cointelegraph.com/news/bitcoin-approaches-11-500-as-top-cryptos-see-gains","text":"Saturday, July 6 — most of the top 20 cryptocurrencies are reporting moderate gains on the day by press time, as Bitcoin (BTC) hovers just ...","img":"https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdGcmi26RdOCRqaQ0kQ8raWmw2uA7PHv3Oi936yUNA8IQN9OhXKS6Rar8gBF_7Jwd_GvRw2UA"}]

for (var i = 0; i < js.length; i++) {
    console.log('<div><a href='+js[i].link+'>'+js[i].title+'</a></div>')
    $('body').append('<div><a href='+js[i].link+'>'+js[i].title+'</a></div>')
/*   $('body').append('<div>'+js[i].text+'</div>') */
}

});
```

This issue is : 
'New ECB Boss Christine Lagarde Made A Serious Bitcoin Warning' is not rendered as a href while 
'Bitcoin Approaches $11500 as Top Cryptos See Gains' is rendered as href

How to generate href for both js array elements ? The code to generate the href is same so is there a value in the js array that is causing this inconsistency ?

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/adrianfiddleuser/jvq7ogk5/66/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the trailing slash at the end of the link:

```
"link":"https://www.forbes.com/sites/billybambrough/2019/07/07/new-ecb-boss-christine-lagarde-made-a-serious-bitcoin-warning/"
```

which results in

```js
$('body').append('<div><a href=https://example.com/foo/>title</a></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Basically, jQuery is incorrectly interpreting the `/>` right before `/>title</a>` as a self-closing tag. But `<a>`s are *not* self-closing in HTML, even with `/>`:

```html
<!-- Renders properly - the tag does not self-close: -->
<a href=https://example.com/>click</a>
```

Surround the attribute in quotes instead, eg `<a href="https://example.com/">title</a>`:

```js
var js = [{
  "title": "New ECB Boss Christine Lagarde Made A Serious Bitcoin Warning",
  "link": "https://www.forbes.com/sites/billybambrough/2019/07/07/new-ecb-boss-christine-lagarde-made-a-serious-bitcoin-warning/",
  "text": "Bitcoin and other crypto-assets have long divided traditional economists and bankers with some warning over their instability and others ...",
  "img": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-cf7C5AWRZ2mt1qip3sV9MzLok1tGn0CAInRO6kqP1J5b_VQQdQRmKXW8NsNi2BTxOYnSl-Q"
}, {
  "title": "Bitcoin Approaches $11500 as Top Cryptos See Gains",
  "link": "https://cointelegraph.com/news/bitcoin-approaches-11-500-as-top-cryptos-see-gains",
  "text": "Saturday, July 6 — most of the top 20 cryptocurrencies are reporting moderate gains on the day by press time, as Bitcoin (BTC) hovers just ...",
  "img": "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdGcmi26RdOCRqaQ0kQ8raWmw2uA7PHv3Oi936yUNA8IQN9OhXKS6Rar8gBF_7Jwd_GvRw2UA"
}]

for (var i = 0; i < js.length; i++) {
  $('body').append('<div><a href="' + js[i].link + '">' + js[i].title + '</a></div>')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or, to be more elegant and safe, rather than writing out HTML manually, create an `<a>` explicitly, and assign to its `href` property and its `textContent`:

```js
var js = [{
  "title": "New ECB Boss Christine Lagarde Made A Serious Bitcoin Warning",
  "link": "https://www.forbes.com/sites/billybambrough/2019/07/07/new-ecb-boss-christine-lagarde-made-a-serious-bitcoin-warning/",
  "text": "Bitcoin and other crypto-assets have long divided traditional economists and bankers with some warning over their instability and others ...",
  "img": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-cf7C5AWRZ2mt1qip3sV9MzLok1tGn0CAInRO6kqP1J5b_VQQdQRmKXW8NsNi2BTxOYnSl-Q"
}, {
  "title": "Bitcoin Approaches $11500 as Top Cryptos See Gains",
  "link": "https://cointelegraph.com/news/bitcoin-approaches-11-500-as-top-cryptos-see-gains",
  "text": "Saturday, July 6 — most of the top 20 cryptocurrencies are reporting moderate gains on the day by press time, as Bitcoin (BTC) hovers just ...",
  "img": "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdGcmi26RdOCRqaQ0kQ8raWmw2uA7PHv3Oi936yUNA8IQN9OhXKS6Rar8gBF_7Jwd_GvRw2UA"
}];

js.forEach(({ link, title }) => {
  $('<div><a></a></div>')
    .appendTo('body')
    .find('a')
    .prop('href', link)
    .text(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, by 'safe' are you referring to from a security point of view ?

Comment: Yes, and it's also more predictable when you know for sure no more elements will be created than you're expecting. Eg, with your current code, a `<script>` tag inside  a `title` or `link` property could be executed, and more child elements than just the `<div><a>` could be created

Answer (score 1):

This is because your link that doesn't render properly ends with `/`, and finally you get something like `<a href=link/>` and `/>` is being interpreted by jQuery as closing of `<a>` tag, so it basically rewrites it to `<a href=link></a>`. You need to put the link between quotes to avoid that behaviour.

Comment: HTML5 doesn't actually need quotes any more, but I feel dirty not using them. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-attributes

Comment: But it's jQuery that does that, not browser.

Comment: You could either remove the trailing slash, or add quotes, both would solve the problem. If it were me, I would do both. You answered the question correctly, I just though I might mention it.